# Implement implicit Writes for result of join query

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

Compilation error:

```
No Json serializer found for type Seq[(models.Account, models.Company)]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

---

How can I define an implicit writes for the result of a join query?

Controller:

```
def someEndpoint = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val query = for {
        a <- accounts if a.id === 10
        c <- companies if a.companyID === c.id
    } yield (a, c)
    db.run(query.result).map(rows => Ok(Json.toJson(rows)))  // Causes compilation error
}
```

---

Each of my models (account and company) have their own implicit writes (here's the company one):

```
case class Company(id: Int, name: String)

object Company {
  implicit val writes = new Writes[Company] {
    def writes(company: Company): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "id" -> company.id,
        "name" -> company.name
      )
    }
  }
}
```

---

Is it possible to dynamically handle serializations for joins?  I have a lot of things I will be joining together... Do I need to explicitly define a `writes` for each combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Writes.seq` will help you

small writer

```
val w = (
  (__ \ "account").write[Account] and 
  (__ \ "company").write[Company]
).tupled
```

helps you can transform `Seq[(models.Account, models.Company)]` to `JsValue` with

```
Writes.seq(w).writes(rows)
```

and last command will be

```
db.run(query.result).map(rows => Ok(Writes.seq(w).writes(rows))
```

or a more clear variant

```
db.run(query.result)
  .map(
    _.map{
      case (a,c) => Json.obj("account" -> a, "company" -> c)
    }
  )
  .map(rows => 
    Ok(JsArray(rows))
  )
```

it's the same thing, but you create object for every row yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you expect the response of your query in JSON to be something like

```
[
  {
    "account" : { "number": "123", "companyID" : 1 },
    "company" : { "id" : 1, "name" : "My company"}
  } , ...
]
```

The problem is the response of the query is just a tuple, so "account" and "company" are not easy to calculate.

Instead of a tuple you could create a new case class with the joined data, but I understand you want to avoid that. In that case you can instead of a tuple use a Map that is something that will convert automatically to JSON.

**Extra:** Creating writers for case classes is very simple

```
import play.api.libs.json._
implicit val personWrites = Json.writes[Person]
```

Reference: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonInception

Comment: How do I get the query to return a map instead of a tuple?

Comment: You can do it in your for comprehension  yield Map("account" -> Json.toJson(a), "company" -> Json.toJson(c)) or map the rows and create the Map just when creating the response.